# Why does addition of long variables cause concatenation?

Tags: java, long-integer, string-concatenation, addition

What does Java do with long variables while performing addition?

Wrong version 1:

```
Vector speeds = ... //whatever, speeds.size() returns 2
long estimated = 1l;
long time = speeds.size() + estimated; // time = 21; string concatenation??
```

Wrong version 2:

```
Vector speeds = ... //whatever, speeds.size() returns 2
long estimated = 1l;
long time = estimated + speeds.size(); // time = 12; string concatenation??
```

Correct version:

```
Vector speeds = ... //whatever, speeds.size() returns 2
long estimated = 1l;
long size = speeds.size();
long time = size + estimated; // time = 3; correct
```

I don't get it, why Java concatenate them.

Can anybody help me, why two primitive variables are concatenated?

Greetings, guerda

Comment: tip:   don't use 'l' for longs, as it is indistinguishable from '1' in some fonts. Use 'L' instead.

Comment: You've accepted an answer but that doesn't fully explain what was causing the problem - can you elaborate??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you're not seeing what you think you're seeing. Java doesn't do this.

Please try to provide a [short but complete program](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/complete.html) which demonstrates this. Here's a short but complete program which demonstrates correct behaviour, but with your "wrong" code (i.e. a counterexample).

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Vector speeds = new Vector();
        speeds.add("x");
        speeds.add("y");

        long estimated = 1l;
        long time = speeds.size() + estimated;
        System.out.println(time); // Prints out 3
    }
}
```

Comment: So what was it about this answer that was correct? What was the author doing wrong?

Answer (score 22):

My guess is you are actually doing something like:

```
System.out.println("" + size + estimated);
```

This expression is evaluated left to right:

```
"" + size        <--- string concatenation, so if size is 3, will produce "3"
"3" + estimated  <--- string concatenation, so if estimated is 2, will produce "32"
```

To get this to work, you should do:

```
System.out.println("" + (size + estimated));
```

Again this is evaluated left to right:

```
"" + (expression) <-- string concatenation - need to evaluate expression first
(3 + 2)           <-- 5
Hence:
"" + 5            <-- string concatenation - will produce "5"
```